# default setting for option select

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have been trying for weeks to solve this problem and as a last resort I seek help here.
I am using option tag to display 4 options. When I select an option it loads a .php file. The code I have is not too elegant but it does work.

```
<select name="history" class="button">
<option value="1" selected>Today</option>
<option value="2">Yesterday</option>
<option value="3">This Month</option>
<option value="4">This Year</option>
</select>

<div id="txtHint"><b></b></div>
<script> 
   $('[name="history"]').on('change', function() {
   var ajaxMethod = "today.php";
   switch($(this).val())
   {
   case "1":
     ajaxMethod = "today.php";
     break;
   case "2":
     ajaxMethod = "yesterday.php";
     break;                
   case "3":
     ajaxMethod = "monthly.php";
     break;                
   case "4":
     ajaxMethod = "yearly.php";
     break;      
   }
   $("#txtHint b").load(ajaxMethod);
});
</script>
```

All the .php files have the same table but make different mysql queries.
When I refresh the page, it clears the block and I have to select an option again. Is it possible to load an option as a default when the page loads? Otherwise I have an empty block before making a selection.
I tried having the table in the block and having each file only query the mysql but that does not work.
Any suggestions would be appreciated

For completeness I have included the today.php

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "
        SELECT  max(Tmax), min(Tmin), max(R)  
        FROM  alldata
        WHERE DATE(DateTime) = CURDATE()
        "
    );
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $maxTemp = $row['max(Tmax)'];
      $minTemp = $row['min(Tmin)'];
      $totalRain = $row['max(R)'];
    }
?>
   <table id="historical">
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo 'Maximum'?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo 'Minimum'?>
        </td>       
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/temp.png">
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $maxTemp." °C"?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $minTemp." °C"?>
        </td>       
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/rain.png">
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $totalRain." °C"?>
        </td>       
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing, this is the code that fits the purpose.
It may help other users.

```
<select id="recordsSelector" class="button">
                                <option value="today" selected>
                                    <?php echo "Today"?>
                                </option>
                                <option value="yesterday">
                                    <?php echo "Yesterday"?>
                                </option>
                                <option value="thisMonth">
                                    <?php echo "This Month"?>
                                </option>
                                <option value="thisYear">
                                    <?php echo "This Year"?>
                                </option>
                            </select>


                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>           
                <script>
                    stationData('<?php echo $defaultStats?>');
                    function stationData(period){
                        $(".records").html("");
                        if(period=="today"){
                            $("#almanacheading").html("Today");
                        }
                        if(period=="yesterday"){
                            $("#almanacheading").html("Yesterday");
                        }
                        if(period=="thisMonth"){
                            $("#almanacheading").html("This Month");
                        }
                        if(period=="thisYear"){
                            $("#almanacheading").html("This Year");
                        }
                        $.ajax({
                            url : "almanac.php?period="+period,
                            dataType : 'json',
                            success : function (json) {
                                $("#historyTMax").html(json['maxT']);
                                $("#historyTMin").html(json['minT']);

                                $("#historyHMax").html(json['maxH']);
                                $("#historyHMin").html(json['minH']);

                                $("#historyDMax").html(json['maxD']);
                                $("#historyDMin").html(json['minD']);

                                $("#historyPMax").html(json['maxP']);
                                $("#historyPMin").html(json['minP']);
                            },
                        });
                    }
                    $("#recordsSelector").change(function(){
                        period = $(this).val();
                        stationData(period);
                    });
                    $("#recordsSelector").val('<?php echo $defaultStats?>');    
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To restore the selected option when you refresh the page.. TRY

1.Fetch data from DB to select the default option while loading the page. (If you store the option value in DB).

2. OR Use Sessions or cookie to store the selected data temporarly. And select the default option w.r to session or cookie data.

Comment: @ safin Thanks but it does not help much. When the page initially loads, the block is blank. There is nothing to restore. What I need is have any of the tables displayed in the block rather than an empty one. If I select the first option nothing happens because of 'change' and no change has been made.

Comment: cant u use cookie..?

Comment: there is nothing to store in the cookie if a selection is not made

Comment: then the cookie will be empty...you can check any cookie data exists initially.. right ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. There is no cookie data to check. Can you give me an example of how to set a cookie that has no data?

Comment: initialize cookie variable with empty or null ..then change value accordingly

Comment: That is beyond my experience level. Will have to research further. Must be another way around other than cookies.

Comment: I now know why putting the table in the block instead of the php file I call did not work. I think it's because the variables are local.
What I will try now is to put all the mysql queries in one file, changing the variables of course, then 'include' it. Everything else works.